# Как сохранить html страницу со всеми данными, загруженную в WebView?

Tags: android, java, webview

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется HTML- страница, которая каждый раз при обращении к ней выдает новый контент, соответственно один раз сохранить не получится. Когда загружаешь ее в WebView то ее загрузка занимает до 10 секунд, что не правильно в моем случае, нужно практически мгновенное отображение, поэтому необходимо в фоне подгружать страницу.

Встает вопрос, как сохранить страницу со всем ее содержимом на устройстве, чтобы без проблем потом ее показать?

**UPD:** вариант   с кэшированием страницы в самом ***WebView***    не подойдет, так как нужно показать не предыдущий показанный контент, а новый.

Comment: Как вариант сохранение html текста в preference либо запись в файл? И, соответсвенно, повторное использование?

Comment: такой вариант не подойдет, потому что есть картинки

Comment: но сохраняя ссфлки на картинки легко их востановить. Тем более сохраняя весь html - сохраняются все теги. и WebView способен сам с ними справиться

Comment: @jimpanzer так в том и суть, чтобы картинки были сохранены на устройстве, а если путь к картинке был абсолютный, т.е задан ссылкой, то при отсутствии интернета ничего ведь не знагрузатся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Впринципе идея проста: грузить данные, сохранять их и только потом скармливать `WebView`.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9415274/1616443) подробно описаны все шаги.

Comment: Возникает куча вопросов. Например я никогда не работал с HTML серьезно, и я не знаю как подключаются скрипты, а на странице есть предложенная вами ссылка правильно описывает ответ на мой вопрос, но вот как быть со скриптами и прочей ерундой? Как мне их вытянуть, а самое главное каким образом(в какие файлы, как их потом привязывать) сохранить, чтобы все работало